# Is there a working solution for integrating Neo4j 1.6 in NodeJS?

Tags: neo4j

I have found some relevant modules on Github but they do not work.
Does anyone know of some other available solutions?

Those are the three I have tried:

```
https://github.com/bobby/node-neo4j
https://github.com/gasi/node-neo4j
https://github.com/neo4j/neo4js
```

Answer (score 4):

Go with the repo made by the people who make Neo4J: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4js

Like I mentioned, it is created and maintained by the people behind Neo4J and is constantly updated. I am using this currently in a project and it works fantastically well. Only thing to know is that you need to be running Node.JS 1.6 or better for the modules to work.

If you have any questions drop me a line or you can also ask in their discussion forum here: http://neo4j.org/nabble/

Comment: One thing that bothers me is that they label it a "beginning" and the installation instructions are even wrong (still referring to a contributor's namespace). Any limitations you've encountered?

Comment: The current version of the code in Github is in a project we have nearing production. No problems that I've found, really. If you see something odd you should put an issue up on Github, the team is very responsive.

Answer (score 3):

I'm one of the authors/maintainers of @gasi's node-neo4j (`npm install neo4j`). We have admittedly not upgraded it for 1.6 (we're still on 1.4 here but plan on upgrading soon), but it works entirely well -- we've been using it on our production site for many months now!

Can I ask what the issue is? Btw, we moved the repo to our formal organization's repo: https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j

Comment: Great! I just added a link to the repo in http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/tutorials-rest.html, will point there in some minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: https://github.com/philippkueng/node-neo4j

```
npm install node-neo4j
```

We're currently working on an upgrade to Neo4j 2.0.

It will support insert node with label, indexes on labels, CRUD for labels, constraints and streaming.

My work in progress (fork): https://github.com/Stofkn/node-neo4j